# Flask-Admin: displaying images from S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask, flask-admin

I created a custom `ImageUploadField` in Flask-Admin for uploading images to S3. It's working great, except when I select a single record - the `img src` tag now prepends `/static/` to all of my file routes and I can't see the image. This is the generated tag from Flask-Admin:

```
<div class="image-thumbnail"> <img src="/static/https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/mypicture.jpg"> </div><input class="form-control" id="image1" name="image1" type="file"></div>
```

I also serve static files from my app, so globally changing the `static` directory wouldn't be a good idea.

There appears to be several properties on `ImageUploadField` that can be modified for this need (`endpoint`, `url_relative_path`, `relative_path` and `base_path`) but I was still unable to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `widget` was responsible for generating the URL. It also looks for the image in the `static` endpoint (hence why `endpoint` defaults to `static` when initializing the `ImageUploadField` class). To solve this, I created a subclass of this widget and modified the HTML to point directly to the S3 URL, which get's stored on the form.

Although widgets aren't talked about in depth in the Flask-Admin documentation, you can see how they work from pieces of the [source code](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/form/upload.py#L294).

Below is the full code for the widget, and part of my custom `ImageUploadField`.

```
class S3ImageUploadInput(ImageUploadInput):

    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('id', field.id)
        kwargs.setdefault('name', field.name)

        args = {
            'file': html_params(type='file',
                                **kwargs),
            'marker': '_%s-delete' % field.name
        }

        if field.data and isinstance(field.data, string_types):
            # calling field.data to directly return S3 URL
            url = field.data
            args['image'] = html_params(src=url)

            template = self.data_template
        else:
            template = self.empty_template

        return HTMLString(template % args)


class S3ImageUploadField(ImageUploadField):

    widget = S3ImageUploadInput()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(S3ImageUploadField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Flask-Admin uses `urlparse.urljoin` to create filename, so it may prepend `'/static'` if `'relative_path'` parameter doesn't have a trailing slash.

Just a thought, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

add "endpoint" to dict some_image

```
form_args = dict(
    some_image=dict(
        endpoint=you_url_complete,
        base_path='/some/folder/static',
        relative_path='some_image/',
        url_relative_path='uploads/',
        namegen=your_namegen_func_here,
        storage_type_field='some_image_storage_type',
        bucket_name_field='some_image_storage_bucket_name',
    )
)
```