# How to display images from the static folder uploaded in S3 to your Flask app

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3

I am facing issues displaying images in my flask app. below is my code use
This is my main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import boto3

local_server = True
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'super-secret-key'

s3 = boto3.client('s3',
                aws_access_key_id=os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                aws_secret_access_key= os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
                 )
BUCKET_NAME='my s3 bucket name'

@app.route("/")
def home():
    posts = Posts.query.filter_by().all()
    last = math.ceil(len(posts)/int(params['no_of_posts']))
    #[0: params['no_of_posts']]
    #posts = posts[]
    page = request.args.get('page')
    if(not str(page).isnumeric()):
        page = 1
    page= int(page)
    posts = posts[(page-1)*int(params['no_of_posts']): (page-1)*int(params['no_of_posts'])+ int(params['no_of_posts'])]
    #Pagination Logic
    #First
    if (page==1):
        prev = "#"
        next = "/?page="+ str(page+1)
    elif(page==last):
        prev = "/?page=" + str(page - 1)
        next = "#"
    else:
        prev = "/?page=" + str(page - 1)
        next = "/?page=" + str(page + 1)

return render_template('index.html', params=params, posts=posts, prev=prev, next=next)



app.run(debug=True)
```

this is my html template
layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>{{params['blog_name']}}</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/clean-blog.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">{{params['blog_name']}}</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          Menu
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
            </li>
           
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

{% block body %} {% endblock %}

 <hr>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <ul class="list-inline text-center">
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <a href="{{params['tw_url']}}" target="_blank">
                  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                  </span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <a href="{{params['fb_url']}}" target="_blank">
                  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                  </span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <a href="{{params['gh_url']}}" target="_blank">
                  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-github fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                  </span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <p class="copyright text-muted">Copyright &copy; TheFlaskBlogger 2021</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/clean-blog.min.js') }}"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

This is one of my page
index.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
    <!-- Page Header -->
    <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/img/home-bg.jpg') }}')">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <div class="site-heading">
              <h1>{{params['blog_name']}}</h1>
              <span class="subheading">{{params['tag_line']}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">



     {% for post in posts %}    
          <div class="post-preview">
            <a href="/post/{{post.slug}}">
              <h2 class="post-title">{{ post.title }}

              </h2>

            </a>
            <p class="post-meta">Posted by
              <a href="#">Admin</a>
              on {{post.date}}</p>
          </div>

          {{post.content[0:143]}}
          <hr>
</li></a>
          {% endfor %}


          <!-- Pager -->
          <div class="clearfix">
          

            <a style="border-radius: 12px;" class="btn btn-primary float-left" href="{{prev}}"> &larr; Previous</a>
            <a style="border-radius: 12px;" class="btn btn-primary float-right" href="{{next}}">Next &rarr;</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Please help me display the images from my amazon s3 bucket.I tried all the methods but got no success in displaying images from my S3 bucket. Also note my final outcome is to add the flask application to heroku.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41041307/flask-admin-displaying-images-from-s3) answer your question?

Comment: No I am still confused and facing the same issue. I can display image from local system but I want to display it from s3